# Story Not Found error while running a test using Jbehave Junit

Tags: bdd, jbehave, jbehave-plugin, jbehave-maven-plugin

I have configured my Jbehave test project and has a .story file in the project. I tried using the configuration settings as I found on the internet but when I run the tests, it gives me an error, the stack trace is shown below

```
org.jbehave.core.io.StoryResourceNotFound: Story path 'D:\AutoRegression8.8\NewProject\src\BusinessCase1.story' not found by class loader sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@631d75b9
at org.jbehave.core.io.LoadFromClasspath.resourceAsStream(LoadFromClasspath.java:80)
at org.jbehave.core.io.LoadFromClasspath.loadResourceAsText(LoadFromClasspath.java:65)
at org.jbehave.core.io.LoadFromClasspath.loadStoryAsText(LoadFromClasspath.java:74)
at org.jbehave.core.embedder.PerformableTree.storyOfPath(PerformableTree.java:261)
at org.jbehave.core.embedder.StoryManager.storyOfPath(StoryManager.java:61)
at org.jbehave.core.embedder.StoryManager.storiesOf(StoryManager.java:92)
at org.jbehave.core.embedder.StoryManager.runStoriesAsPaths(StoryManager.java:86)
at org.jbehave.core.embedder.Embedder.runStoriesAsPaths(Embedder.java:213)
at org.jbehave.core.junit.JUnitStories.run(JUnitStories.java:20)
at TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:59)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:271)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:70)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
```

However, I have my .story file in the same location at which the code tries to find it. To find the .story file, I have used the below code:

```
 @Override
protected List<String> storyPaths() {
/*
 * return new StoryFinder().findPaths(
 * CodeLocations.codeLocationFromClass(this.getClass()), "**.story",
 * "");
 */
String placetoSearch = System.getProperty("user.dir") + "\\src\\BusinessCase1.story";
/*return new StoryFinder().findPaths(CodeLocations.codeLocationFromClass(this.getClass()), placetoSearch, "");*/

return Arrays
    .asList(placetoSearch);

}
```

Any help or reference in this regard would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

There's a difference between looking for a file, and looking for a resource.

JBehave uses the classloader you set it up with to look for the story as a resource. A resource is normally part of the packages you're running. That means it needs a filename relative to the root of your classes, rather than an absolute path.

(If you were using `myClass.getResource()` rather than `myClassLoader.getResource()` it would be relative to your class.)

You can also use unix-style slashes if you want to. Try `"/BusinessCase1.story"` as the filename.